# Api Gateway and Lambda function : response body

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to use, in an iOS app, api gateway with a lambda function to interrogate a mongodb database.

The execution works quite fine.
In fact there is something I don't understand in the response model.

In my lambda function, if the key of the dictionnary is anything other than "schools" it doesn't work at all :
**Lambda Function**

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, client) {
        const collection = client.db("test").collection("test2");
        collection.find({}).sort({"ranking_clique" : -1}).toArray(function(err, result) {

            if (err) throw err;
            context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

            var dic = {schools : result} // if I change schools by another word, it doesn't work in the api result (of course I change it in the others body)

            client.close();
            context.done(null,dic);
        });
    });
}
```

**API Gateway Body Response**

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "TestOutputModel",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "schools": {          // // if I change schools by another word, it doesn't work in the api result
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
           "nom": { "type": "string" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**iOS SDK Aws Model**

```
import Foundation
import AWSCore


@objcMembers public class TestOuputModel : AWSModel {

    var schools: [TestApiOutputModel_categories_item]?

    public override static func jsonKeyPathsByPropertyKey() -> [AnyHashable : Any]!{
        var params:[AnyHashable : Any] = [:]

        params["schools"] = "schools"

        return params
    }

    class func schoolsJSONTransformer() -> ValueTransformer{
        return  ValueTransformer.awsmtl_JSONArrayTransformer(withModelClass: TestApiOutputModel_categories_item.self);
    }
}
```

**iOS Aws Model**

```
import Foundation
import AWSCore


@objcMembers public class GetinapiPartnersModel_partners_item : AWSModel {

    var nom: String?

    public override static func jsonKeyPathsByPropertyKey() -> [AnyHashable : Any]!{
        var params:[AnyHashable : Any] = [:]

        params["nom"] = "nom"

        return params
    }
}
```

I didn't generate the iOS Aws SDK. The website doesn't work currently. So I wrote it based on previous app which work.

In synthesis, if I change the key word "schools" by another word in the 3 files, it doesn't work anymore.

Can somebody tell me why ?

Regards

Comment: Have you got any body mappings using 'schools' in your integration response in API Gateway? Have you changed the word schools in Lambda and tested from API Gateway?

Comment: No. I only have one mapping model linked to this api and it's post above. If I change the words schools only in Lambda, the result in Api Gateway begins by {
  "o": [
    { (there is an "o" instead of schools) I don't understand why

Comment: I made the same test again and if choose "example" instead schools in lambda. It appears well in api gateway (even if i didn't change the api gateway model)

Comment: Ok. I found what is the problem : in xcode, in the generated aws api gateway sdk from another app that I modified, there is a function xxxxJSONTransformer where xxxx at the beginning is the schools variable. So if you modified yourself the sdk generated, change the beginning of this function

Comment: Hey! Did you manage to work with lambda functions and API gateway response models ?  i tried everything and i'm getting Transformation Error when using the mapping templates